# Debug more items at same time with a Visual Studio CMake project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cmake, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I've a CMake project that I'm developing with Visual Studio 2019.

I've two executables, a server and a client. I want to debug both of them at the same time. How can I start more that one process with debugger with Visual Studio at the same time, using a CMake project?

EDIT:

My specific use case is: I've a CMake project with two executables, defined with `add_executable(exec1)` and `add_executable(exec2)`. I want to start them at the same time. Actually I can select only one in the "Select Startup Item" button, and when I start one it's grayed and I cannot start the other one.

Comment: There are instructions for debugging multiple VS processes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Switch_processes__break_and_continue_execution__step_through_source). Have you seen these? Do they help with your use case?

Comment: No. See edit in post.

Comment: Hope [this document](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) will help you.

Comment: consider VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS property

Answer (score 0):

> I want to start them at the same time. Actually I can select only one
>   in the "Select Startup Item" button, and when I start one it's grayed
>   and I cannot start the other one.

As far as l know, although you've imported two execute files into the same project,you cannot debug them at the same time in Visual Studio by Debug UI.

**An instance of vs can only launch one executable unless one of the execute files is nested in another execute file.**

**Suggestion**:

1.You can try to open two instances of VS and then you can debug the client side and the server side, respectively. Or debug separately with one VS instance.

**In addition**, please check if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983138/force-serial-execution-for-specific-targets-in-cmake) can help you.

If I misunderstand your issue, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: I can debug multiple executables with a vcxproj project ("Debug -> Debug New Instance" in the context menu), so it *is* possible to launch more then one executable within a single instance of Visual Studio. Why doesn't that work for CMake projects?